# Converting to localtime at client with c#

Tags: javascript, c#, localtime

I have a database with records stored in UTC. The c# .NET application reads the data and populates a *.cshtml table server-side. The server doesn't know the client's timezone as it is not a parameter reported by the browser, and there is no login or user form for the user to enter a profile and declare their timezone. The result is a table displayed in UTC at the browser.
I am aware that if the value is in a javascript variable then it is trivial to get the browser to make timezone offset adjustment. However, the data reaches the browser as a set of TD tags with text between.

Any solution I can think of to convert this to local time is inelegant - using javascript to walk through the table, get the innerHTML, parse it, adjust it, and put it back. That feels like an awful solution. Is there a better way? Pass the data as a JSON object and dynamically create the table via javascript? again it feels unwieldy. Is there a simpler way to make the browser take the values between the TD> tags and adjust, like

```
<TD> onsomething="this.innerHTML=adjustTime("2017-06-17 09:00:00");> </TD>
```

or a better way?

Comment: i would go for the JSON / AJAX solution, creating the table dynamically when the data is returned. you could pass the browser's timezone offset in the request. getting it would be as simple as `var d = new Date()
    var offset = d.getTimezoneOffset();`

Comment: You could also have JavaScript set a query parameter that states what the current offset is and use that to render the local time.

Comment: thanks Tim/Phuzi - If I got the JAX/JSON route then I think I don't need to pass the browser's offset to the server, I can just apply it locally. I was hoping there might be an obvious simple way, but suspect you are right about the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A general rule when dealing with times in different zones is to store & transmit the value in UTC and then allow the 'view' to display it as appropriate i.e. in the users current timezone.

I would add an API that provides a list of times in UTC, then allow the javascript client to render and display them as appropriate